# Vertex attribute bindings from multiple VAOs in one shader

Tags: opengl, glsl, vertex-shader

Suppose I have a vertex shader with the following vertex attributes:

```
layout(location = 0) in vec4 foo1;
layout(location = 1) in vec4 bar1;
layout(location = 2) in vec4 foo2;
layout(location = 3) in vec4 bar2;
```

And two VAOs which were initialized like this:

```
glBindVertexArray(vao1);
...
glVertexAttribPointer(0, ...);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, ...);

glBindVertexArray(vao2);
...
glVertexAttribPointer(2, ...);
glVertexAttribPointer(3, ...);
```

Then, if I bind them successively:

```
glBindVertexArray(vao1);
glBindVertexArray(vao2);
glDrawArrays(...);
```

what data will I get from `foo1` and `bar1` vertex attributes? Can I expect their values to be taken from buffer pointed by vao1, or will their state be undefined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL objects are not like macros (except for display lists, which actually are like macros). They store state. When you bind a new object to the same target as a previous object, all of the governed state is taken up by the new object; the old one is unbound from that binding point.

Each VAO contains state for *all* of the available vertex attributes. The attributes default to being disabled. As such, if you only enable attributes 2 and 3 in a VAO, then when you bind that VAO, only attributes 2 and 3 will be enabled.